# Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" org.hibernate.QueryException: could not resolve property: Id of:

Tags: java, mysql, swing, hibernate

This is my Hibernate Statment. It should tell me how much my order cost.
Or Can i use something other to get the costs?

```
 public Query sum() {
            Session session = NewHibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
            Transaction transaction = session.beginTransaction();
            Query baum = session.createQuery("SELECT SUM(Anz_Normal*Preis_normal+Preis_family*Anz_family) from Bestellung,Pizza p,Kunde where p.Id = pizza and Email = 'a@f'");

            transaction.commit();
            return baum;

        }
```

Here do I  run it in my Programm :

```
Query cost = bestellungRepository.sum();
    jLabel3.setText(cost + " €");
```

And this is the Error i get. I already dry to use createSQLQuery() but this didnt help.

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" org.hibernate.QueryException: could not resolve property: Id of: pizzahibernate.model.Pizza [SELECT SUM(Anz_Normal*Preis_normal+Preis_family*Anz_family) from pizzahibernate.model.Bestellung,pizzahibernate.model.Pizza p,pizzahibernate.model.Kunde where p.Id = pizza and Email = 'a@f']
    at org.hibernate.QueryException.generateQueryException(QueryException.java:137)
    at org.hibernate.QueryException.wrapWithQueryString(QueryException.java:120)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.doCompile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:234)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.compile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:158)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:126)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:88)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.QueryPlanCache.getHQLQueryPlan(QueryPlanCache.java:190)
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl.getHQLQueryPlan(AbstractSessionImpl.java:301)
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl.createQuery(AbstractSessionImpl.java:236)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.createQuery(SessionImpl.java:1796)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.hibernate.context.internal.ThreadLocalSessionContext$TransactionProtectionWrapper.invoke(ThreadLocalSessionContext.java:356)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy5.createQuery(Unknown Source)
    at pizzahibernate.repository.BestellungRepository.sum(BestellungRepository.java:41)
    at pizzahibernate.Bestellung2.bestellung(Bestellung2.java:132)
    at pizzahibernate.Auswahl.jButton1ActionPerformed(Auswahl.java:433)
    at pizzahibernate.Auswahl.access$300(Auswahl.java:18)
    at pizzahibernate.Auswahl$5.actionPerformed(Auswahl.java:185)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2018)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2341)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6516)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3320)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6281)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2229)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4872)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2287)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4698)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4832)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4492)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4422)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2273)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2719)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4698)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:735)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(EventQueue.java:103)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:694)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:692)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:87)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:708)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:706)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:705)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:242)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:150)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:146)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:138)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:91)
Caused by: org.hibernate.QueryException: could not resolve property: Id of: pizzahibernate.model.Pizza
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractPropertyMapping.propertyException(AbstractPropertyMapping.java:83)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractPropertyMapping.toType(AbstractPropertyMapping.java:77)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.toType(AbstractEntityPersister.java:1978)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.FromElementType.getPropertyType(FromElementType.java:367)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.FromElement.getPropertyType(FromElement.java:500)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.DotNode.getDataType(DotNode.java:649)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.DotNode.prepareLhs(DotNode.java:272)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.DotNode.resolve(DotNode.java:219)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.FromReferenceNode.resolve(FromReferenceNode.java:126)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.FromReferenceNode.resolve(FromReferenceNode.java:121)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.HqlSqlWalker.resolve(HqlSqlWalker.java:945)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.expr(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:1264)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.exprOrSubquery(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:4639)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.comparisonExpr(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:4111)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.logicalExpr(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:2096)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.logicalExpr(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:2021)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.whereClause(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:794)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.query(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:595)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.selectStatement(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:299)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.statement(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:247)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.analyze(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:278)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.doCompile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:206)
    ... 54
```

Can someone help me?+

This is my Pizza Class:

```
package pizzahibernate.model;

import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
@Entity
public class Pizza implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 6946049944294004465L;
    @Id
    private int id;
    private String text;
    @Column(name="NAME")
    private String pName;
    private float preis_normal;
    private float preis_family;

    public Pizza() {
    }

    public Pizza(final int Id, final String pName, final String Text,final float Preis_normal,final float Preis_family) {
        this.preis_normal = Preis_normal;
        this.preis_family = Preis_family;
        this.id = Id;
        this.text = Text;
        this.pName = pName;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(final int id) {
        this.id = this.id;
    }

    public String getText() {
        return text;
    }

    public void setText(final String Text) {
        this.text = Text;
    }

    public String getpName() {
        return pName;
    }

    public void setpName(final String pName) {
        this.pName = pName;
    }

    public float getPreis_normal() {
        return preis_normal;
    }

    public void setPreis_normal(final float Preis_normal) {
        this.preis_normal = (int) Preis_normal;
    }

    public float getPreis_family() {
        return preis_family;
    }

    public void setPreis_family(final float Preis_family) {
        this.preis_family = (int) Preis_family;
    }

}
```

If i write that id in the Select query small it give no Error but i get as output : QueryImpl(SELECT SUM( Anz_Normal*Preis_normal+Preis_family*Anz_family)from Bestellung,Pizza p,Kunde where p.id = pizza and Email = 'a@f'€

Comment: It seems your pizza model has no field called Id, as the error message says.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be **id** instead of **Id** in the query.

```
Query baum = session.createQuery("SELECT SUM(Anz_Normal*Preis_normal+Preis_family*Anz_family) from Bestellung,Pizza p,Kunde where p.id = pizza and Email = 'a@f'"
```

Comment: If i write that id in the Select query small it give no Error but i get as output : QueryImpl(SELECT SUM( Anz_NormalPreis_normal+Preis_familyAnz_family)from Bestellung,Pizza p,Kunde where p.id = pizza and Email = 'a@f'€

Comment: You need to execute the query. Use baum.list() or baum.uniqueResult() as per your need. Also check the value you are assigning for the id parameter.